# mimetypes.guess_type is not recognising video/x-m4v on python3.7.3

Tags: python-3.7, mime-types, m4v

Following code:

```
import mimetypes
file_name = 'ipho2001.m4v'
mimetypes.guess_type(file_name)
```

On python 2.7.13 it returns `('video/x-m4v', None)`

On python 3.6.2 it returns `('video/x-m4v', None)`

On python 3.7.3 it returns `(None, None)`

On python 3.8.2 it returns `(None, None)`

Why? and how to recognise mimetype in python3.7.3?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why (I will accept a detailed answer if someone will post it). But this is how I have solved it:

```
mimetypes.add_type('video/x-m4v', '.m4v')
```